# How to make multiple threads write to a single file, with predefined sections(by line numbers)?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm

Suppose I have 5 threads, and already pre assigned line numbers in a file associated to threads, for example thread 1 writes to line no. 1 to 5 , thread 2 writes to 6 to 10 ...thread 5 writes to 21 to 25. I want to write a Java program that can do this in a parallel way(i.e not locking the file by a single thread)

Comment: Lines of text file could have different length. So there is a problem - how to get right position for writing...

Comment: You would need a filesystem that supports concurrent access (i.e. multiple read/write positions within a single file). I don't know of any operating system that supports such a file system.

Comment: Why would you need this? Writing to a file will be hundreds of times slower than anything a regular thread can do. The IO is the bound here, not the processing power.

Comment: Without further context, concurrently writing to a single file sounds like a wrong approach for all typical scenarios that I can think of (as mvd pointed out). Assuming there is heavy work that benefits from concurrent execution *before* you write to file, have that part run in concurrently, use an appropriated datastructure to accumulate the results and one dedicated thread to write them to file.

Comment: I guess Java NIO offers something like that. To the question why i would want to do that. I would like to finish the creation of a file much faster by using multiple threads writing to their pre defined regions.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here will be to use NIO API's that are available in Java. Specifically you will be interested in [FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html)

Just to quote the documentation here  , in the interest of whats important

> A file channel is a SeekableByteChannel that is connected to a file.
>   **It has a current position within its file which can be both queried
>   and modified. The file itself contains a variable-length sequence of
>   bytes that can be read and written and whose current size can be
>   queried.**
>
> A region of a file may be locked against access by other programs.
>
> **File channels are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads.** The
>   close method may be invoked at any time, as specified by the Channel
>   interface.